# libvirt error when trying to 'hot' attach-disk on guest with "Channel qemu-ga"

Tags: qemu, kvm, libvirt, virsh

I have `KVM` virtual machine running `CentOS` 7 as guest `OS`. I'm trying to attach an additional disk to it on the run (without shutting it down) using this command:

```
$ sudo virsh attach-disk centos --source /var/lib/libvirt/images/newdisk.img --target sdb --persistent
```

But receive an error:

```
error: Failed to attach disk
error: internal error: cannot update AppArmor profile 'libvirt-d2e7bbb8-c7b3-44ec-b0ea-27539e0df732'
```

If I do the same with `Debian` guest - everything is ok.

What is difference, how to solve that?

**UPDATE:**

I have a comment!

I compared two `VM`'s xml and saw that `CentOS` have `QEMU-agent` in his configuration:

```
<channel type="unix">
    <source mode="bind" path="/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/channel/target/centos_auto.org.qemu.guest_agent.0"></source>
    <target name="org.qemu.guest_agent.0" type="virtio"></target>
    <address bus="0" controller="0" port="1" type="virtio-serial"></address>
</channel>
```

Then I removed "channel qemu-ga", restarted `VM` and checked "hot add" feature. It worked.

I tested it on other `VM`s (`CentOS`, `Fedora`, `Debian`) and saw the same.

As a result:

1. If enable `qemu-agent` i cannot use `hot plug`.
2. If use "hot plug" i must forget about agent.

*Is it my mistake in configuration or these features can't work together?*

Host-OS: `Ubuntu` 15.10

`QEMU` emulator: now `2.4.92` (tested `2.3` and `2.4.1`)

`VMM`: 1.3.0

Comment: It is most likely a bug. What is the host OS? Does it have AppArmor (I'm guessing yes). What is your setting of `security_driver` in `/etc/libvirt/qemu.conf`? It would be also good to enable debugging info according to [this post](http://wiki.libvirt.org/page/DebugLogs) and then try going from there, either submitting a bug or asking on the mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

This is a clear bug in the apparmor security driver for libvirt. The existence of the QEMU guest agent config in the XML should have no impact on ability to hotplug disks to a guest. This bug should be reported to the libvirt upstream, or Ubuntu bug trackers.